# App Scripts spreadsheet error

Tags: google-apps-script

Does anyone see a reason for an "Unexpected error" when deployed to Google App Scripts...something in doPost?  Running the function produces no errors.

```
function doGet() { 
  var app = UiApp.createApplication(); 
  var form = app.createFormPanel(); 
  var flow = app.createFlowPanel(); 
  flow.add(app.createTextBox().setName("textBox")); 
  flow.add(app.createListBox().setName("listBox").addItem("option 1").addItem("option 2")); 
  flow.add(app.createSubmitButton("Submit")); 
  form.add(flow); 
  app.add(form); 
  return app; 
} 

function doPost(eventInfo) { 

  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  ss.getRange("A1:A1");
  ss.getActiveRange().setValue("hello");  

  return app; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()` only works in Spreadsheet container bound scripts. Otherwise you need to use `SpreadsheetApp.openById` and specify the spreadsheet key to get.

When you "run the function" are you just running the doGet? If you select doPost in the dropdown and run it, you should see an error if this is not a Spreadsheet bound script.

Comment: since the doPost function doesn't make use of eventinfo both functions run without error from the script editor if written in a spreadsheet script editor (which I suppose is the case here). As Kalyan says, once you're 'out' of the spreadsheet scope (when you deploy it) the spreadsheet becomes 'undefined'