# Google Apps upload from spreadsheet: cannot reference active cell

Tags: event-handling, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this google app script which should

1. show file upload dialog
2. store file in google drive
3. write the url of the file into the **current cell**

All goes well except step 3, where the cell updated is always cell A1 in the first sheet. But the cursor is on sheet #3 on another cell.

```
function onOpen(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var menuEntries = [];
  menuEntries.push({name: "File...", functionName: "doGet"});
  ss.addMenu("Attach ...", menuEntries);
}

function doGet(e) {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle("Attach file to sheet");
  var form = app.createFormPanel().setId('frm').setEncoding('multipart/form-data');
  var formContent = app.createVerticalPanel();
  form.add(formContent);  
  formContent.add(app.createFileUpload().setName('thefile'));
  formContent.add(app.createSubmitButton('Submit'));
  app.add(form);
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().show(app);
  return app;
}

function doPost(e) {
  var fileBlob = e.parameter.thefile;
  var doc = DocsList.getFolderById('0B0uw1JCogWHuc29FWFJMWmc3Z1k').createFile(fileBlob);
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var label = app.createLabel('file uploaded successfully');
  var value = '=hyperlink("' + doc.getUrl() + '","' + doc.getName() + '")'

  app.add(label);
  app.close();
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveCell().setValue(value);
  return app;
}
```

I tried `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveCell().setValue(value);` outside of the doPost() function and this works when called in a normal context. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

judging from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14530583/119861), it is not possible to get the current spreadsheet/cell from the `doPost` function, the way I got it working is to get it in the `doGet` function via hidden fields and pass it via the form. Full blown working example [here](http://howto.pui.ch/post/73949358752/how-to-attach-a-file-to-google-spreadsheet).